# Small signal analysis of current mirror

Tags: current-mirror

[image]

I have problem getting the output resistance of this current mirror.
How should I draw the small signal circuit and derive the output resistance equation?

Comment: The **procedure** for drawing the small signal equivalent circuit is **the same** as for a standard current mirror or any other circuit really.

Comment: First draw a standard 2-FET current mirror with all the input and output biasing, then insert a test current (AC, so is small signal) to the output.

Comment: Hi I have tried using a test source. But I still can’t manage to get output resistance equation given

Comment: Must be a current-test-source. And your model must include the output resistance of the FET (the lambda effect, or in bipolars its called the Early Voltage Effect). What is the bias point for the output transistor? 10uA and 1.5 volts?

Comment: If we were to ignore the body effect and the bias resistor? The circuit is designed in mos. If we were to get the output resistance, we need to have the small signal circuit. Then apply test source, let’s say Vx at the output. Then Ix follow from Vx into the circuit. Ro is obtained by Vx/Ix. I know the procedure but I can’t get the output resistance equation. The circuit analysis of the small signal model is troubling me.

Comment: *Must be a current-test-source* **Not true**, I would use a **DC voltage source** connected to the output in series with an **AC voltage source**. Then I plot the 1/(AC current) to get the impedance. Using a current source to determine Rout is much more difficult as you have to get the DC biasing current **exactly** right. If you don't then the DC voltage at the output will be incorrect for the mirror to operate properly. For a voltage output (like opamp output) I would use a current source to determine Rout.